# parallel asynchronous processing with callbacks in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, callback

I am making a rails app and I am wondering whether it is possible to setup an asynchronous/callback architecture in the controller layer. I am trying to do the following:

When a HTTP request is made to /my_app/foo, I want to asynchronously dish out two jobs - a naive ranking job and a complicated ranking job both of which rank 1000 posts - to several worker machines. I want to setup a callback method in the controller for each job which is called when the respective job is finished. If the complicated job does not return within X milliseconds, I want to return the output from the naive job. Otherwise, I want to return the output from the complicated job.

It is important to note that I want these jobs to performed in parallel. What is the best way to implement such a system in Rails? I am using Apache Phusion Passenger as my rails server if that helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to issue several HTTP request asynchronously in Rails. However, it's impossible to make Rails event-driven.

In can send several HTTP request asynchronously with libraries such as [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus). However, you might have concurrency issue if your timeout is too long.

Otherwise, you can try some event-driven web framework such as [Cramp](https://github.com/lifo/cramp) and [Goliath](http://postrank-labs.github.com/goliath/). They are both based on EventMachine, so you can try [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should be using background jobs. In that case, when a request comes in, you would start / queue two jobs which would be picked up and processed by a worker, which acts independently of your Rails app.
Here a few links that could be of help:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs
http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job
http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker
http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque
http://rubyrogues.com/queues-and-background-processing/

Answer (score 0):

Try using rabbitmq where you can post a message on queue and expect the response in reply queue. The queue consumer can be even implemented in Scala for fastness. amqp gem would suffice what I am saying. Rails controller with amqp binding would be even more nice if possible(I am exploring that option having endpoints with amqp binding instead of http). That would solve enough no of problems